Crime A or Crime B, same crime under different circumstances, don't know which
I was originally curious about "If they know you committed crime A or crime B, but don't know which one, can they convict you" and found this question If one has committed illegal act A or B, but we cannot prove that A was committed or B was committed, is one generally proven guilty of a crime? and people seemed to agree that you can't be convicted or even charged, because "The common law requires that a defendant is entitled to be told not only of the legal nature of the offence with which he or she is charged, but also of the particular act, matter or thing alleged as the foundation of the charge."
But what if Crime A and Crime B are the same? Like if they know you murdered Bob or Joe, but don't know which one. Maybe that should be technically the same as killing an unidentified man, but it feels different. Or if they know you killed Bob on Monday in his car or on Tuesday at his house, but don't know which.
I feel like regardless you are guilty of like one count of murder. Can they just find you guilty of murder without saying who or when? Or do they need to know which one it was?
This is just a curiosity question, I am in the US but any jurisdiction is fine.

"Can they just find you guilty of murder without saying who or when?" Almost surely not. But, I don't have the time to look up the case law that says so. Also, the circumstances that would create this situation are not at all clear and might add insight to an answer. If we can prove he killed John Doe at 3 p.m. on Tuesday in the dining room, but can't ID John Doe and have two candidates for who John Doe might be, that is very different from "if they know you killed Bob on Monday in his car or on Tuesday at his house, but don't know which" where it is hard to see how it could happen.

If the prosecution doesn't know whether Bob is dead or alive, or whether Bob died on Monday or Tuesday, or whether a dead body was found in a car or in a house - how can they say whether it was murdered, and by whom? The examples just make no sense.

@ohwilleke Two people simultaneously shoot Joe and Bob. Ballistic evidence shows which gun killed each of them, but there's no way to tell which perp was weilding each gun (they wore gloves so no fingerprints on the guns).

canada
If the Crown does not particularize the identity of the victim in the charge, the Crown need only prove that the accused committed the offence against a person unknown.
See e.g. R. v. Ferguson-Cadore, 2020 ONSC 7094 at para 9:

To prove the charges, it is not essential for the identity of the victim to be known.  However, the Crown having particularized the name of the victim, on the basis of the above authorities the correct course appears to be, in the absence of ability to prove the name of the alleged victim, for the Crown to seek to amend the indictment to remove the reference to Beverly Ann O’Grady and change it to conform with the evidence heard at trial.

